# Are Custom Functions resources for Excel JS API still available?

Tags: office-js

This is a very vague question but I'm unsure of where else to ask. Earlier this month, Microsoft Dev released the Custom Functions feature for the Excel JS API. I started writing an add-in that uses this feature and when I left last week on Friday, the add-in was fully operational.

However, when I came in on Monday, I tried to run the exact same add-in and I'm receiving an "Error installing functions" notification when I try inserting the add-in. Nothing at all has changed in my code. I tried debugging this yesterday, completely proofed my manifest file, but have not been able to come up with a result. Furthermore, this "Error installing functions" error doesn't include any more information. Does anyone know how to investigate this error?

I'm wondering if something happened to the availability of the Custom Functions feature over the weekend? Has anyone else been experiencing issues with Custom Functions? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi yes they are still available. Please see https://aka.ms/customfunctions.

Debugging for the runtime on windows is still under development. For your specific issue, this can help you with guidance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-best-practices#debugging  (specifically see the link to enable runtime logging, which will show you errors registering your custom functions).

UPDATE: we also now require an "ID" parameter. This may be why your functions are no longer registering. This is to support the ability to have localized function names and descriptions.

If all else fails, please [send us a frown](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-do-i-give-feedback-on-microsoft-office-2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11). This will send us additional log information to track and debug your values.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Keyur, thank you so much!! That worked like a charm. Back up and running now :)